# Loading data to Scylla DB on GKE with sstableloader, getting "Error creating netty channel to /10.110.117.172:9042"

Tags: cassandra, google-kubernetes-engine, netty, scylla

In Scylladb while using sstable loader to load data, we are facing the following error-

```
root@scylla-chronicle-s-1:~# sstableloader -d 10.110.68.9 /var/lib/scylla/data/connections/by_date-4ce6c340f5dd11e980df000000000002/snapshots/1658173631835

Using /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml as the config file
===== Using optimized driver!!! =====
WARN  19:51:22,937 Error creating netty channel to /10.110.117.172:9042
com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.110.117.172:9042
        at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:218) ~[scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38) [scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120) [scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399) [scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464) [scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131) [scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_292]
ERROR 19:51:22,942 Unexpected error while executing task
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.closeAsync(HostConnectionPool.java:838) ~[scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.removePool(SessionManager.java:437) ~[scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.onDown(SessionManager.java:525) ~[scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.onDown(Cluster.java:2033) ~[scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.access$1200(Cluster.java:1393) ~[scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager$5.runMayThrow(Cluster.java:1988) ~[scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ExceptionCatchingRunnable.run(ExceptionCatchingRunnable.java:32) ~[scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_292]
        at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [scylla-driver-core-3.7.1-scylla-2-shaded.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_292]
WARN  19:51:22,948 Error creating pool to /10.110.117.172:9042
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted indicates that the machine where you are running `sstableloader` doesn't have network connectivity to the IP.

You need to make sure you are connecting to an IP that is reachable by clients. If the cluster is running on GKE, there's a good chance that you need to setup host networking so the cluster is accessible from outside GKE.

Usually, the pods are accessible via a Kubernetes service configured on GKE. See [Accessing Scylla on a Kubernetes cluster for details](https://operator.docs.scylladb.com/master/generic.html#accessing-the-database). Cheers!